# How can I take the log of a column after using Numpy.where()?

Tags: python

[Textfile](https://file.io/S3X122XhEGXR) I imported this text file using genfromtxt and created columns:

```
name = np.genfromtxt('textile.txt',unpack=True,dtype=int,usecols=(11)) ## Read in integer types

ID, SExtractor_ID, x_pos, y_pos, phot, aega, Mo, S, W = np.genfromtxt('textfile.txt',unpack=True,dtype=float,usecols=(0,1,3,4,7,8,9,10,12)) ## Read in float types

str_ID, ACS_F6, ACS_F8 = np.genfromtxt('textfile.txt',unpack=True,dtype=str,usecols=(2,5,6)) ## Read in strings
```

I used `x = np.where((0.47 < phot) & (phot<= 0.62))` to create a new array. but when I try to get take the log using something like `y = np.log10(x[phot])`,

I'm unable to get the output, and instead get the error "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index". Is there a way to do this?

File contents

```
## Columns are
## 0 = Running ID
## 1 = Numerical ID from Source Extraction Catalog
## 2 = Name or String ID from Source Extraction Catalog
## 3 = x pixel position
## 4 = y pixel position
## 5 = Number of  ACS
## 6 = Number of ACS
## 7 = Photometric redshift z
## 8 = Aega
## 9 = Mo
## 10 = S
## 11 = w
## 12 = 1 or 2
        0.000000000000000        0.000000 GEMSz033259.77m275136.0        1317.200        156.8000 h_goods_s01.fits s1z01A_sci.fits       0.5620000        23.33900    7.415330E+08       0.4363117 2        2.746105
        1.000000000000000        1.000000 GEMSz033259.80m275153.4        1867.800        340.5000 s1v01A_sci.fits s1z01A_sci.fits       0.7130000        23.96200    1.100603E+09       0.7677434 2        4.474493
        2.000000000000000        3.000000 GEMSz033259.21m275154.0        1795.600        594.2000 s1v01A_sci.fits s1z01A_sci.fits       0.8760000        23.62900    2.496597E+09        1.750781 2        7.626086
        3.000000000000000        4.000000 GEMSz033300.86m275307.3        4342.700        737.6000 s1z01A_flx s1z01A_flx       0.1270000        21.97900    2.663721E+08      0.02119955 2       0.1082317
        4.000000000000000        5.000000 GEMSz033259.78m275223.3        2800.900        687.7000 s1v01A_sci.fits h_goods_z01.fits       0.7590000        23.83600    4.614623E+09       0.7065185 2        5.712100
        5.000000000000000        6.000000 GEMSz033300.12m275251.2        3726.300        862.1000 h_goods_s01.fits h_goods_z01.fits       0.8330000        22.94800    9.556979E+09        2.224697 2        6.896655
        6.000000000000000        7.000000 GEMSz033301.20m275329.3        5082.900        845.5000 s1v01A_sci.fits s1z01A_sci.fits       0.7170000        22.60500    3.839872E+10       0.5853211 2        4.519726
        7.000000000000000        9.000000 GEMSz033301.28m275348.6        5700.700        1033.700 s1z01A_flx s1z01A_flx        1.022000        23.02400    6.238305E+09        4.048824 2        10.50426
        8.000000000000000        10.00000 GEMSz033300.62m275334.2        5149.100        1142.300 s1v01A_sci.fits s1z01A_sci.fits       0.6190000        22.74600    2.300714E+09       0.9743091 2        3.346452
        9.000000000000000        11.00000 GEMSz033300.23m275316.1        4522.500        1102.400 s1v01A_sci.fits h_goods_z01.fits       0.5360000        23.33700    1.177480E+09       0.2962289 2        2.488070
        10.00000000000000        12.00000 GEMSz033259.20m275237.7        3163.700        1094.900 s1v01A_sci.fits s1z01A_sci.fits       0.7220000        23.97300    9.478382E+08       0.7123680 2        4.587853
```

Comment: it's a lengthy text file, but that is one object of the text file with all the columns

Comment: I updated the question and included how I imported the file